# Python Time Series Forecast Flat Line

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I'm trying to forecast the prices of conventional and organic avocados using ARIMA model, but it shows a flat line for the forecast. 
I used historical data from Jan 2015 to March 2018 to forecast, and the lowest AIC value to fit the model. After I reset index for conventional avocado, there are only 169 samples. I'm not sure where it went wrong. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

```
org = avo[avo['type']== "organic"]
con = avo[avo['type']== "conventional"]

con_avo = con.groupby('Date'['AveragePrice'].mean().reset_index()
con_avo = con_avo.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(con_avo['Date']))

org_avo = org.groupby('Date')['AveragePrice'].mean().reset_index()
org_avo = org_avo.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(org_avo['Date']))

mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                            order=(0, 1, 0),
                            seasonal_order=(0, 0, 0, 12),
                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                            enforce_invertibility=False)
con_results = mod.fit()

y = con_avo['AveragePrice']
forecast = con_results.get_forecast(steps=100)
pred_ci = forecast.conf_int()
ax = y.plot(label='Observed', figsize=(14, 7))
forecast.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, 
label='Forecast')
ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
            pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
            pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k',alpha=.25)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Average Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This is what I currently get:

[image: forecast of average price of conventional avocado]

Comment: Thia question is better suites for SE/stats. You can get better help there.

Comment: The confidence interval seems to come thru ok. If you look at the `forecast.predicted mean` you see the constant values I imagine?

Comment: Yes I see constant values for forecast.predicted_mean. I'm not sure why the forecast line is flat since historical data has seasonality with a few cycles ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583538/arima-produced-slope-straight-line/56730867#56730867

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. I changed the parameters of SARIMA and the forecast line wiggles a little in the front and the rest is straight. Is there a way to improve the forecast or this might be the best result ?

Comment: what accuracy you are getting ?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to increase the accuracy of model.